# Merging reports and charts

Tags: jasper-reports, report, birt, pentaho

We are planning to use one of the Pentaho, Birt or Jasper for our reporting and charting needs. We will be embedding the reporting and charting component in our web applications. All these reporting tools have report and chart designed in a XML format.

We are looking for a capability where we can merge different individual charts and report to build a super report. Does anyone has any idea, insight, links in this direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The dashboarding mechanism (CDF) in Pentaho sounds ideal for that and is very dynamic.  I'm fairly sure it can be embedded within an existing web application.

Alternatively if your super report is more static, Pentaho reports or any reporting mechanism that has good subreports is another option.  I frequently build large reports that are made up of 10-20 individual subreports - sometimes they are interrelated, sometimes independent little reports.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT supports report libraries that allow you to use components (charts, data sets, tables) over and over again in any combination across your corpus of reports.  You can do the patchwork report building either by including the library in your project inside the BIRT IDE or via the APIs at run-time.